# Can be the "public" folder moved inside the "src" folder?

Tags: next.js

[Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory) that there is a possibility to use `src` folder in Next.js.
I think this is a good pattern to separate actual business logic from app configs.
It would feel natural to me to put the `public` folder also under the `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

No. The `public` folder has to be in root folder

> Config files like `next.config.js` and `tsconfig.json` should be inside the root directory, moving them to src won't work. **Same goes for the `public` directory**